# Update sqlite database based on changes in production

Tags: python, django, sqlite, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a Django App using Elastic Beanstalk on AWS. The app has a function whereby user can register their details.

The problem is when I make small changes to my app and deploy this new version I loose the registered users since their information isn't in my local database (only the database on aws).

Is there any way to download the modifications to the database during production so that I can keep these changes when I redeploy.

I'm not using AWS RDS, I simply bundle the .SQLite file with my source code and deploy to Elastic Beanstalk.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Don't bundle the development .sqlite file with the production stuff. It needs to have its own .sqlite file and you just need to run migrations on the production one

Comment: @Pblove Sounds like an answer to that question. Would you not like to make Q/A pair?

Comment: @Yunnosch may as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't bundle the development .sqlite file with the production stuff. It needs to have its own .sqlite file and you just need to run migrations on the production one.

Comment: To create an environment on elastic beanstalk don't you have to compress your source code and upload the .zip file to aws. I don't see how you can have a separate production database to run migrations on doing this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just don't include your SQLite file in the zip and create a new SQLite file on aws.